# auto refresh and fetch unique values from excel table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, unique, auto-update

I have a table(Column B), I need to get the unique values alone after removing the duplicates in Column D.

if I add a new entry in B6 as "Delta", it should come in D4 automatically.

Please help

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have access to the UNIQUE formula.

Comment: @BigBen - No I could see only UNICHAR and UNICODE in my "Insert Function" list

Comment: To have this auto updated you need to either have office 365 or use vba. In that case update the tags to vba.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving column A&B the same. put (number) 1 in C1. Then in C2 put `=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B2,$B2)=1,C1+1,C1)` then drag downwards.

Then in D1, put in `=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(A1,$C:$C,0)),"")` and drag downwards.  Done. Now you should have the new list.